# how can I extract only emoji from utf-8 with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, encoding, utf-8, emoji

env python3.6
There's a utf-8 encoded text like this

```
text_utf8 = b"\xf0\x9f\x98\x80\xef\xbc\x81\xef\xbc\x81\xef\xbc\x81"
```

And I want to search only elements which three numbers or alphabets follow `b'\xf0\x9f\x98\'` - this actually indicates the facial expression emojis.

I tried this

```
if re.search(b'\xf0\x9f\x98\[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$', text_utf8)
```

but it doesn't work and when I print it off it comes like this `b'\xf0\x9f\x98\\[a-zA-Z1-9]{3}'` and `\` automatically gets in it.
Any way out? thanks.

Comment: You escaped `[` - is that intentional? That ruins the character class.

Comment: sorry i don't get you,  what ```[``` you're pointing out?

Comment: Does `if re.search(b'\xf0\x9f\x98[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$', text_utf8)` work?

Comment: sorry I a bit modified my question. yeah it makes no error actually, it says it only doesnt match

Comment: I just converted `\x80\xef\xbc\x81\xef\xbc\x81\xef\xbc\x81` and it shows `ï¼ï¼ï¼`  - you can't match them with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, these are not alphanumerics.

Comment: thanks. I just want to match only this part ```\xf0\x9f\x98\x80```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194825/discussion-between-user9191983-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2):

I can see two problems with your search:

1. you are trying to search the textual *representation* of the utf8 string (the `\xXX` represents a byte in hexadecimal). What you actually should be doing is matching against its *content* (the actual bytes).
2. you are including the "end-of-string" marker (`$`) in your search, where you're probably interested in its occurrence anywhere in the string.

Something like the following should work, though brittle (see below for a more robust solution):

```py
re.search(b'\xf0\x9f\x98.', text_utf8)
```

This will give you the first occurrence of a 4-byte unicode sequences prefixed by `\xf0\x9f\x98`.

Assuming you're dealing **only** with UTF-8, this should TTBOMK have unambiguous matches (i.e.: you don't have to worry about this prefix appearing in the middle of a longer sequence).

---

A more robust solution, if you have the option of third-party modules, would be installing the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module and using the following:

```py
regex.search('\p{Emoji=Yes}', text_utf8.decode('utf8'))
```

This has the advantages of being more readable and explicit, while probably being also more future-proof. (See [here](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp) for more unicode properties that might help in your use-case)

Note that in this case you can also deal with `text_utf8` as an actual `unicode` (`str` in py3) string, without converting it to a byte-string, which might have other advantages, depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks! it worked for the given case in the question but how can I avoid numbers? it actually gives priority to numbers and it doesnt pick up only emojis...

Comment: To which answer are you referring? First or second?